# Asp.Net: Is gridview is the only way to display data in data base ??

Tags: asp.net

Is grid is the only way to display data in the data base ??

i want to display the data in a lable.. I this possible for below code.. ??

protected void cnt_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{
    con = new SqlConnection(Str);
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select Count(emp_id) from emp_tbl", con);
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    gridview.DataSource = dr;
    gridview.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

The above code runs successfully for gridview display.. but i want to display count it in lable tool.. i had tried like this

//lable.Text = Convert.ToString(dr);

//lable.DataBind();

but it's wrong.. pls let me get rid of this problem... thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do this:

```
lable.Text = dr.GetInt32(0).ToString();
```